# Tensorflow(IOS) - compiled binary size

Tags: ios, tensorflow

i have been trying tensor-flow over the last few days, however im obtaining the following compile sizes for "libtensorflow-core.a" when using "compile_ios_tensorflow.sh" with options "-Os" or "-O3".

I have obtained the following for arm64 and armv7:
arm64 - 97.4 MB
armv7 - 99,3 MB

Edit: I know that when referencing the native tensorflow libraries (for example) on a Xcode project, when compiling that project the app has around 26 MBs. However if im native linking the compiled static libraries to a xamarin project in C# it includes the full size of the statically linked library per architecture, so around 100 MBs per architecture.

So what i was looking for originally was how to reduce the .a size.

Comment: Have you tried to tried to build an actual executable with it? In my experience (in Linux and WIndows), the static lib (.a) takes a lot of space because it has many symbols (function names), but when you actually use it to build a program those are stripped and the final size is _reasonable_.

Comment: Yes i built an executable with it, i should have been more specific on what im doing. Im using the compiled static libraries of the C++ tensorflow version and linking those with a C# xamarin project, that when compiled includes the full size of the .a static libraries

Answer (score 0):

You should find that the sizes that you are seeing are just what you see on your local disk. The library files you see on your local disk don't reflect the size of what's added to the final binary. May I suggest that you try and build the app and look at the package size.

Please see this github issue thread here for more information the last time this was asked: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10483

Bonus: You can also quantize your graphs to reduce the size of your model assets.

Comment: Yes i know that exact issue thread, and yes im already using a quantized model of inception_v3. I have updated my post.